# Failed parallel trend assumption in covariate for difference in difference analysis

Tags: econometrics, experiment-design, difference-in-difference

Performing a difference in difference analysis and the parallel trend assumption fails  for the treatment and control groups for a potential covariate to include in the analysis.

Would it be ok to perform the DiD analysis but not include the covariate that makes the treatment and control groups have different trends in the pre treatment period?

Also, as a curiosity say I have a control and treatment group but decided to break the treatment group into two separate groups T1 and T2.  Further assume that T2 has a different trend than C and T1 but when  the T1 and T2 are combined the assumption holds would it be correct to use the combined Treatment T=T1 and T2?  Thanks

Comment: Why do C and T groups need to have a parallel trend for the covariate?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I may be wrong but I thought they did because if I include that covariate in my model the results would be biased if say the outcome in the control with respect to that variable was increasing prior to intervention and the outcome of the treatment group was decreasing prior to intervention.

Comment: My understanding is that you need parallel trends for the outcome, conditional on covariates. I have never seen that requirement for covariates themselves. If you have seen this spelled out somewhere, please add a link or citation with page numbers.

Comment: I agree maybe my question was not clear  but that is what my question is asking. If the control and treatment groups have differing trends  conditional on a particular variable but it holds  if that variable is removed can I just remove the offending variable from the analysis and proceed?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, but your comment clarified it. You mean that the trends are not parallel conditional on some covariate, and you want to remove it, which fixes the problem. I think in such cases theory and domain expertise are the best guide. For instance, could this variable be effected by the expectation of coming treatment (like with Ashenfelter Dip with job training)? Could it be altered by the treatment itself? If so, conditioning on it would be a bad idea. To maximize the chance of a good response, you may want to provide some details on the setting.